# Django rest framework drf-yasg swagger multiple file upload error for ListField serializer

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

I am trying to make upload file input from *swagger* (with `drf-yasg`), but when I use **`MultiPartParser`** class it gives me the below error:

```
drf_yasg.errors.SwaggerGenerationError: FileField is supported only in a formData Parameter or response Schema
```

My view:

```py
class AddExperience(generics.CreateAPIView):
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser]

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = DoctorExperienceSerializer
```

My serializer:

```py
class DoctorExperienceSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    diploma = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.FileField(allow_empty_file=False)
    )
    education = serializers.CharField(max_length=1000)
    work_experience = serializers.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

I also tried `FormParser` but it still gives me the same error. Also: `FileUploadParser` parser but it works like `JsonParser`:

Comment: I'm currently facing this issue. Have you been able to solve this yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `OpenAPISchema` (`OAS`) 2 doesn't support the multiple file upload (see issue [#254](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/254)); but `OAS 3` supports it (you can use [this YML spec](https://pastebin.com/Evs3m0ht) on a [live swagger editer](https://editor.swagger.io/) ([see this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CByFf.png))).

Comes to the real issue, [there is a section in the drf-yasg's doc](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/readme.html#openapi-3-0-note),

> If you are looking to add Swagger/OpenAPI support to a new project you might want to take a look at drf-spectacular, which is an actively maintained new library that shares most of the goals of this project, while working with OpenAPI 3.0 schemas.
>
> OpenAPI 3.0 provides a lot more flexibility than 2.0 in the types of API that can be described. drf-yasg is unlikely to soon, if ever, get support for OpenAPI 3.0.

That means the package `drf-yasg` doesn't have support for `OAS3` and thus, it won't support the *"multiple file upload"* feature.

You can consider migrating from `drf-yasg` to [`drf-spectacular`](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/). But, also note that, `drf-spectacular` is also dealing the FileUpload in [a different way](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#filefield-imagefield-is-not-handled-properly-in-the-schema).